# if greater than zero copy from the range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm useless with vba but I need one code to help me with my assignment. I have data sheet with "product" list in range B38:B161 and "to order" column in range I38:I161 which will be updated manually. so when cells in range "I" is updated with number to order, the product from range "B" will be copied to range J38:J161 first empty cell. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you

Script I've got:

`Sub copyAboveZero()
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Set sourceRng = ActiveSheet.Range("I38:I161")
i = 1
For Each cell In sourceRng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.Resize(1, 1).Copy Destination:=Range("J" & i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell
End Sub`

But this code copies only range "I" more than zero cells, while what I want is to copy cells from Range "B" and paste it to range "J" if that makes sense.

Example:

`Column B Column I Column J`

`text1        0        text2`

`text2        6        text4`

`text3        0        text5`

`text4        12`

`text5        24`

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are here to help however not here to do homework without a little effort shown first. There are people who are paid to do this as supposed to the community who is donating their time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't HAVE to have the whole thing totally automated, you can achieve it with relative simplicity using one additional column and a pivot table:

Have, in column J (the example below for cell J38)

=IF(I38 <> 0, 1,0)

This will set the cells in column J to be 1 for each I cell that is above 0.

Now select columns B to J, and Insert-> Pivot Table   . Select to have it on the same sheet.

Drag "Product" (column B) to the pivot table "ROWS" and drag column J to the "FILTERS" area. Select only the value "1" for the filter.

Now, each time after column I is updated, right-click -> Refresh the pivot table, and it will have the list of products you are looking for.

The pivot table can be set to refresh automatically when you open the file.

A kind-of similar way is to have in column J:

= IF(I38 > 0, B38, "")

and then use Auto-filter on column J, for location where the column is not empty. Again - this means un-filtering each time to update column I, then re-applying the filter. Very simple but possibly not as automated as you want...

Michael

Comment: Thank you Michael for your help, but I found what I was looking for and it is fully automatic `=iferror(index(B38:B161, small(if(I38:I161>0, row()-37, ""), row()-37)), "")`